# progress bar inside javascript lightbox starts when lightbox appears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a jquery progress bar and I place it inside a javascript light box. The problem is that I want the progress bar to start only when I click on lightbox to open. The way I have it until now makes progress bar to start when main page loaded. Any idea how to fix this? This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/D9NBY/

```
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block' ">
OPEN</a>

<div id="light" class="white_content_stats">

<div class="prog">
    <div id="filler" class="filler"></div>
</div>


<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'"> 
</br>CLOSE</a>

<div id="fade" class="black_overlay_stats"> </div>
```

My jquery

```
<script>

var stepSize = 50;
setTimeout((function() {
var filler = document.getElementById("filler"),
percentage = 0;
return function progress() {
  filler.style.height = percentage + "%";
  percentage +=1;
  if (percentage <= 100) {
    setTimeout(progress, stepSize);
 }
}

}()), stepSize);

</script>
```

My CSS

```
 .black_overlay_stats{
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 1000%;
        z-index:1001;
        -moz-opacity: 0.6;
        opacity:.70;
        filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    }
    .white_content_stats {
        display: none;
        position:fixed;
        top: 15%;
        width: 300px;

        padding: 30px;
        margin-left:10px;
        background-color:#F2F2F2;   

        border-radius: 0px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);    
        z-index:1002; 
    }



.prog {
    height: 300px;
    width: 30px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    position: relative;
}
.filler {
    height: 0%;
    width: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: I would either use an existing lightbox plugin with callbacks to do the work, or extend how you open your lightbox. You want to initialize the progressbar only when the lightbox is visible, so you can create another function that handles both showing the lightbox and initializing the progressbar

Comment: any idea how to do this ? can u do it using my jsfiddle :   http://jsfiddle.net/D9NBY/

Comment: I can do it, yes! but that's not how the site works ;). Give it a try and come back if you need more help.

Comment: if I knew I would have done it